# Heroku - Migrating from SSL Endpoint to Heroku Automated Certificate Management SSL

Tags: heroku, ssl-certificate

we have a Heroku app running on a subdomain "https://api.blahblah.com".
Originally the app was set up using an Add-On "SSL Endpoint" for https, which is expiring in a few days.  We are interested in migrating from the old SSL Endpoint to the Heroku Automated Certificate Management SSL.  However, I am unsure how to proceed to avoid unforeseen problems and configure the new SSL in the simplest way possible. After going over the available documentation, it seems that we could just use the new Heroku SSL GUI dashboard to configure the new SSL and Automated Certificate Management

[image]

From what I can see in the dashboard and from what I have read in the documentation, I should be able to simply click on "configure SSL" here:

[image]

And then check "automatically configure" here:

[image]

Finally, after waiting 24 hours for the new SSL to be created and to propagate, we would then disable and delete the old "SSL Endpoint".

Ideally, we would like to do this in the simplest way possible, using the Heroku GUI and avoiding the command line. Any insight that anyone can give us into completing this process would be much appreciated!